# magento-coding-standard how to make magento 2 standard work?

Tags: magento2, magento-coding-standard

i'am install this https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard, i installed it via composer and i see there is a package in vendor/magento/magento-coding-standard, and also i modified composer.json according to composer.json

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "([ $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE -eq 0 ] || vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/)"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "([ $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE -eq 0 ] || vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/)"
    ]
}
```

vendor/bin/phpcs -i

```
The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, PSR1, PSR12, PSR2, Squiz and Zend
```

Magento2 standard still not being added, anyone know how to get it works?

Comment: after type "composer update" , the commands work